# "a bytes-like object is required" but I am using bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, bytesio

With Python3 I have re-opened stdout in binary mode. After that when I `print("Hello")` it tells me that I need to use a bytes-like object. Fair enough, it's in binary mode now.

However when I do this:

```
print(b"Some bytes")
```

I *still* get this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print()` **always** writes `str` values. It'll convert any arguments to strings first, including bytes objects.

From the [`print()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*.

You can't use `print()` on a binary stream, period. Either write directly to the stream (using it's `.write()` method), or wrap the stream in a [`TextIOWrapper()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to handle encoding.

These both work:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write(b'Some bytes\n')  # note, manual newline added
```

and

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
import sys

print('Some text', file=TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout, encoding='utf8'))
```